# R - dataframe with character column to json

Tags: r, json

I have dataframe where 1 column is formatted as character but it is actually json. I noticed that on stackoverflow there is lot of questions related to jsons but it didn't find scenario like this.

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at  
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
3            107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
4            109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
5            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
6            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)
```

Since that column is very long, I'll put it here:

```
df$verification
#> {"data": {"verify_client_by_params_response": {"@xmlns": "Bank of America", "verify_check": "AJDSA34&"}}}
class(df$verification)
#> list
```

What I want to do is parse this character to json and then create for each of that separate column, like this

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at    @xmlns          verify_check
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07   Bank of America  AJDSA34&"
    , header=TRUE)
```

This `dput()` contains the complete data frame for the example:

```
structure(
  list(
    id = c(107L, 107L, 107L, 109L, 109L, 110L),
    date = c("2016-12-16", "2017-11-27", "2017-11-28", "2016-11-28", "2017-11-29", "2017-12-04"),
    paid_at = c("2017-06-02", "2017-06-02", "2017-06-02", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01"),
    binded_at = c("2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07"),
    verification = c(
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: No, that json is part of df dataframe but since it is long i didn't wanted to put it to example.

Answer (score 0):

The simple version of the answer when all jsons contains the same values is as follows:

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at  
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
3            107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
4            109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
5            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
6            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)

df$verification  <- '{"data": {"verify_client_by_params_response": {"@xmlns": "Bank of America", "verify_check": "AJDSA34&"}}}'

dt2 <- sapply(df$verification, function(x) unlist(jsonlite::fromJSON(x)$data[[1]]))
dt2 <- t(dt2)
rownames(dt2) <- NULL
dt2

cbind(df[,-5], dt2)
```

If jsons are different (they contain different fields) maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52647197/10441348 (the question was about parsing xmls, not jsons, but the idea was pretty the same).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ndjson)
library(tidyverse) 

structure(
  list(
    id = c(107L, 107L, 107L, 109L, 109L, 110L),
    date = c("2016-12-16", "2017-11-27", "2017-11-28", "2016-11-28", "2017-11-29", "2017-12-04"),
    paid_at = c("2017-06-02", "2017-06-02", "2017-06-02", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01"),
    binded_at = c("2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-07"),
    verification = c(
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}",
      "{\"data\": {\"verify_client_by_params_response\": {\"@xmlns\": \"Bank of America\", \"verify_check\": \"AJDSA34&\"}}}"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  class = "data.frame"
) -> xdf

bind_cols(
  xdf,
  ndjson::flatten(xdf$verification, cls = "tbl") %>% # this completely "flattens" the JSON in the columns
    set_names(
      sapply(strsplit(colnames(x), "\\."), last) %>% # the column names are super long as a result so clean them up
        sub("@", "", ., fixed = TRUE)
    )
) %>% 
  select(-verification)
##    id       date    paid_at  binded_at           xmlns verify_check
## 1 107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07 Bank of America     AJDSA34&
## 2 107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07 Bank of America     AJDSA34&
## 3 107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07 Bank of America     AJDSA34&
## 4 109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07 Bank of America     AJDSA34&
## 5 109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07 Bank of America     AJDSA34&
## 6 110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07 Bank of America     AJDSA34&
```